# Proof that the monster group is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

I was reviewing an abstract algebra book, and I get the comment that "the monster group" (the set of matrix of size $196833 \times 196833$) has no normal subgroups,I wanted to know if anyone knows any proof of this fact or bibliography of the subject, greetings!

PD: The book is "Abstract Algebra , T. Judson"

Comment: That "monster group" is not "group of monsters".  One way is by the list of all 193 nontrivial irreducible characters and note each of them have trivial kernel.

Comment: The group is called "monster group" just because of its insane large number of elements. It is one of the sporadic simple groups

Comment: A first step is to show that the monster group $G$ is perfect, i.e., that $[G,G]=G$. This follows from the fact that it is a Hurwitz group, so can be generated by elements $g,h$ with $g^2=h^3=(gh)^7=e$. Indeed, every Hurwitz group is perfect.

Comment: Of course showing that it is a hurwitz group was the result of a huge amount of very clever computer calculations,

Comment: Note that the Monster group is not *the* set of $196833\times 196833$-matrices. It is a set of *some* invertible complex $196883\times 196883$-matices.

Comment: Lamma $31.5$ in the book 'Sproadic groups' by Michael Aschbacher states that the Monster group is simple.